# How to set a return value if array has some value which is not set

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a code like this

```
int rpindex = allObjects.Find(new Guid(policyGuid));

if (rpindex != -1)
{
    rp = (ResourcePolicy)allObjects.GetAt(rpindex);
}
```

and this is Find method

```
public virtual int Find(Guid guid) 
{
    try 
    {
       for (int i=0; i<this.Count; i++)
       {
           if (guid.Equals(this[i].Guid))
          {
             return i;
          }
       }
    }
    catch(System.Exception exception)
    {
       SpoDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Exception Occurred: " + exception.ToString() );
    }

    SpoDebug.DebugTraceVerbose(func, "no find. guid=" + guid.ToString());
    return -1;
}
```

As of now the existing function Find() outcome is -1 or some integer value[i]. The -1 value will come in two situations , that is if the input is empty [ null value]  and if the input is some value which is not in the database or in the current list, i need change here.That mean if the input to Find() is empty or null that time only it should return -1, otherwise if input has some value and it is not maching then it shud return return -2.SO there should be three outcomes one is -1 second is -2 and third is integer value ,Can any body guide me here 
if i add else loop, i am not sure what return value i can use here other than -1, and integer value

Comment: if i add else loop, i am not sure what return value i can use here other than -1, and integer value

Comment: Please edit your question rather than comment on it. And also edit the code so that it will look more.. readable

Comment: The null check should be outside the function. Although you could have used any other negative value for null in the function but that doesn't look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just after the for loop check

```
if(i == this.Count) //i reached the end of the loop but no matches found
{
 return -2;
}
```

Comment: But if the code makes it that far then i == this.Count anyway.

Comment: @shane try it first. add a not null check in the start to avoid exceptions. Exceptions are slower.

Comment: @Pinakin, that's wrong. Exceptions ARE a little tiny bit slower, but unreadable code is a the real disaster you want to avoid.

Comment: i am using if(i == this.Count) //i reached the end of the loop but no matches found
{
 return -2;
}
the check u provided working fine without adding exception

Comment: i need to test it thouroughly, since my project is complex

Comment: @Oren A, I prefer not to suggest design changes on questions. We do not know what kind of client code is written to call this function. If you suggest, he should throw exceptions, it will require changes to his client code. Having said that, I agree exceptions might make things clear but its not a golden rule..

Comment: @Pinakin, do you really believe his "client code" currently supports -1 and -2 returned values?? Can any code be readable if it supports arbitrary integer values as return codes? What if he said he currently returns -234563 for "not found" and 467453221 for "empty list" and had asked how to check if these values were returned, would you still "not suggest design changes on questions"? What if someone had asked you what eyes cover is good for driving? Would you recommend him the best brand you know or try to explain him covering your eyes while driving is not a good idea?

Comment: @Oren, Ok I see your point and agree completely. Exceptions are better. Just its hard to convince people to see things differently as he is more focused on specifics. May be a specific answer with a note on alternative design is a better bet. Lets rest this here on a happy note :)

Comment: I never argue with happy notes.

Answer (score 2):

Just place extra return statements, or am I missing something?

i.e.

```
try  
{    
    for (int i=0; i<this.Count; i++)    
    {
        if (guid.Equals(this[i].Guid))
        {          
              return i;
        }
    }
    return somethingElseHere;
 }
```

Comment: @Math, I am dumb.. didnt realize he is using return if there is a match :).

Comment: but if input has some value other than null and if it is not matching in the current list then only it should return -2, other wise -1 for null ,,but iam not sure this will work

Comment: @shanethomson11 That just means you replace the return somethingElseHere with more conditional statements depending on what you want to do.  You could even place a case statement there for the various situations if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be more readable to throw an exception in case the list is empty, right after the start of the method:

```
if (this.Count==0)
  throw new InvalidArgumentException();  
//rest as before
```

Having more than one integer value for error is very unclear.